# How to change state when Button pressed?

Tags: react-native

I'm new to React Native and unfamiliar with js.

I want the program to show what I wrote in `TextInput` when I pressed the `Button` (there's a `Text` below the `Button`). I figured maybe I should make two state: put state1 `text` as `Text` input, and put state2 `mimin` as `TextInput` input, and when Button `pressed`, put state2 `mimin` to state1 `text`.

I've tried with the code below but it gave me Red Page when I click the `Button`.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  Button,
  TextInput,
  Alert,
  View
} from 'react-native';

export default class Hella extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {text: '', mimin: ''};
}

render() {
   return (
       <View style={styles.container}>

        <TextInput
          style={{height: 40}}
          placeholder="Type here to translate!"
          onChangeText={(mimin) => this.setState({mimin})}
        />
        <Button
          onPress={onButtonPress}
          title="Learn More"
          color="#841584"
          accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this purple button"
        />
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          {this.state.text}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  }
});

const onButtonPress = () => {
  Hella.setState({
      text: Hella.state.mimin  -------> where the error happened
    });
};

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Hella', () => Hella);
```

The error was

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Hella.state.mimin')

onButtonPress
<project location>/index.android.js:61
```

What did I do wrong? How should I declare it? Where can I learn more?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your `onButtonPress` should be inside `class` since you want to do `setState`

```
export default class Hella extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    ...
  }

  onButtonPress = () => {
    this.setState({
      text: this.state.mimin
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      ...
      <Button
        onPress={this.onButtonPress}
        ...
      />
      ...
    );
  }
}
```

React Native uses a lot of React concepts. Learning basics of React will help you a lot https://facebook.github.io/react/tutorial/tutorial.html

Comment: Finally it worked! Thank you very much (again)! :) I'll also try the link

Answer (score 1):

The function definition should be like below.

```
onButtonPress = () => {
    this.setState({
      text: this.state.mimin
    });
}
```